# returning data from an external sub (in word) called using .Run in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Having failed to resolve the problem I had running Word VBA routine from within an Excel VBA routine. I opted to run the sub externally in word by using `Call wdApp.Run(.....` and passing the values to the Word `sub` from the Excel `sub`.

The macro in Word searches for certain phrases. It works but..    The problem now is how to pass the outcome of the search back to the Excel `Sub`.

Comment: A `Sub` procedure doesn't return a value. Make it a `Function`.

Comment: BTW `Call` is absolutely redundant. Remove it and to `wdApp.Run ...` instead (no parens) ..to invoke a `Sub`. What you'll want is `result = wdApp.Run(...)` (with the parens).

Answer (score 0):

`Sub` procedures don't return anything. You need a `Function`.

```
Public Function GetFoo(ByVal bar As Long) As Long
    GetFoo = bar * 42 'assign to the function's identifier to set return value
End Function
```

Then you can get its return value:

```
Dim result As Long
result = wdApp.Run("GetFoo", 10)
```